# Video-js wordpress plugin & rtmp

Tags: wordpress, rtmp, video.js

1. I have successfully managed to get video-js working with an rtmp from amazon cloudfront using vanilla html. Is there anyway of doing this from the Video-js Wordpress plugin ?
2. Incidentally, various github comments suggest that it's possible to get signed urls to work with video-js but I have not yet succeeded. I get the message ...
   FLASH: Failed to play (stream ID:1)
3. I mention the last point because if the answer to number 1 is "yes, you can use rtmp via the wordpress plugin", I'd like to know if you can do that for signed urls as well ;-)

With thanks in anticipation ...

R.